# Unable to load dynamic library 'redis.so' on php8.1 with igbinary

Tags: php, redis

```
Expected behaviour

Actual behaviour

I'm seeing this behaviour on

OS: Mac OS 12.1

Redis:6.2.6

PHP:8.1

phpredis:5.3.5
$ pecl install igbinary // 3.2.7
$ pecl install zstd
$ pecl install redis

Steps to reproduce, backtrace or example script
[13-Jan-2022 20:34:31] NOTICE: PHP message: 

PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'redis.so' (tried: `/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20210902/redis.so` (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20210902/redis.so, 0x0009): symbol not found in flat
```

namespace '_igbinary_serialize'), /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20210902/redis.so.so (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20210902/redis.so.so, 0x0009): tried: '/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20210902/redis.so.so' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/redis.so.so' (no such file), '/usr/lib/redis.so.so' (no such file))) in Unknown on line 0

Answer (score 1):

```
guys i used this other option for things to work

cd /tmp
git clone https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis.git
cd phpredis
phpize
./configure
make && make install
run this to find the directory -> php-config --extension-dir
then edit your php.ini file
extension=redis.so

this worked like charm
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis/issues/2056 @bot you can verify someone added comment here.